# dart constructor return null

Tags: flutter, dart

This is MainPage class I pass parameters from one class to MainPage class. Before passing the argument I print the list. List values are not null. But after pass the parameter to MainPage returns null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rummy/gameLogic/mainpage.dart';

class Cards extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cards({Key? key, this.cardStatus}) : super(key: key);
  final bool? cardStatus;

  @override
  State<Cards> createState() => _CardsState();
   }

  class _CardsState extends State<Cards> {
 List<String>? userPickedList = [];
  List<String> list = [
'1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
'5',
'6',
'7',
'8',
'9',
'10',

  ];
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.0001,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: ReorderableListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex--;
          }
          final String item = list.removeAt(oldIndex);
          list.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
          GestureDetector(
            key: ValueKey(index),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                userPickedList!.add(list[index]);

                widget.cardStatus! ? list.removeAt(index) : null;
                Mainpage(
                  //   tappedStatus: tapped,
                  userPick: userPickedList?.last,
                );
                print(userPickedList?.last);
              });
            },
            child: Card(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 16.7,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Text(list[index]),
              ),
            ),
          )
      ],
    ));
   }
  }


import 'package:rummy/gameLogic/cards.dart';

class Mainpage extends StatefulWidget {
const Mainpage(
  {Key? key, this.tappedStatus,this.userPick, 
 this.shuffledCard})
  : super(key: key);
final bool? tappedStatus;
final String? shuffledCard;
 final String? userPick;

@override
_MainpageState createState() => _MainpageState();
 }

class _MainpageState extends State<Mainpage> {
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();



}

  bool cardDrop = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.white, child: Cards(cardStatus: cardDrop)),
    ),
    Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.8,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Shuffled card',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        )),
    Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.8,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.userPick.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        )),
    Positioned(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 38,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              cardDrop = true;
              Cards(cardStatus: cardDrop);
              if (widget.tappedStatus == true) {
                cardDrop = false;
                Cards(cardStatus: cardDrop);
              }
              // Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: const Center(
                child: Text(
              'Drop Card',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            )),
          ),
        ))
  ],
);
 }
}
```

This is my full code.

I have two class mainpage and cards. Both are passing arguments with each other.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Please consider that if you have to use a `!` to override null-safety *in your own code*, you are making a mistake. This feature is a last chance workaround to be able to work with code you cannot change, not to let you be lazy in your own coding.

Comment: By the way, if MainPage is not supposed to get a null parameter, why not make the parameter non-null? Then your compiler can tell you where your problem is.

Comment: I don't where is a mistake.  i pass a string to mainpage but I use a text widget to show that string.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace the `userPickedList!.last`
with `userPickedList?.last`

Comment: still i am getting null

Answer (score 0):

If you make your MainPage *visible* (for example give it a pink background) you will see that your problem is not with your parameter being null, your problem is that it is never displayed at all.

It's not in the tree of the build method.

It is hard to know what you *wanted* to achieve. You need to put your MainPage into the tree of visible elements you return from your build function. Your Cards class has the same problems. It's nto in the tree you return from your build method. It will never be visible.

In addition, I encourage you to read a tutorial for null-safety, you are making your life a lot harder than it should be. Once you understand it, there will be a lot less guessing and a lot less `!` to place around your code. The better you get at it, the more helpful your compiler messages will become.

Comment: I print the parameter but it returns null. if parameter does not contain any data then it return null in a text. If any value occur then it return that value. But it return only null. I change color but nothing happened.

Comment: Your MainPage is never displayed, because it is not in the tree you return. Just ask yourself, where would you *expect* MainPage to appear? And why? You never said where it should be on the page, what it's parent is. This is not a problem with your parameter.

Comment: ok, I understand what is solution.